# Function that insert words into text

Tags: python

I have a text that goes like this:

```
text = "All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood."
```

How do I write a function hedging(text) that processes my text and produces a new version that inserts the word "like" in the every third word of the text?

The outcome should be like that:

```
text2 = "All human beings like are born free like and equal in like..."
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am new to Python. It would be great if people are receptive in helping others rather than asking the unhelpful question "Have you tried anything?".

Comment: It would be great if people read some of the [site rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @bereal: fyi: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic/172760#172760

Comment: @thg435 thanks, will take into use.

Comment: Some people should know that not everyone knows as much as you. It would be great if some people can be more understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of giving you something like

```
  solution=' like '.join(map(' '.join, zip(*[iter(text.split())]*3)))
```

I'm posting a general advice on how to approach the problem. The "algorithm" is not particularly "pythonic", but hopefully easy to understand:

```
 words = split text into words
 number of words processed = 0

 for each word in words
      output word
      number of words processed += 1
      if number of words processed is divisible by 3 then
          output like
```

Let us know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like that:

```
' '.join([n + ' like' if i % 3 == 2 else n for i, n in enumerate(text.split())])
```

Comment: this adds a trailing `'like'` to the end, actually this might be wanted so I'm not sure

Comment: yup I wasn't sure either. I posted this to demonstrate the use of basic python tools, not quite sure it's a good answer to give to a newcomer to python though, anyway...